# Cancel notification not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to cancel/delete the notification after I click the addAction.

However it's not working. The notification is still there after the click. 
I'm pretty sure this worked in an other project.

Can anyone see a stupid error I made, why its not working?

**Actual code:**

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

    showNotification(context);

}

private void showNotification(Context context){


    String onderwerp = ("Medicatietijd");
    String name = ("Het is tijd om je medicitie in te nemen.");

    // Geluid notificatie
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    // Notificatie trigger
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, Test.class), 0);

    // De notificatie
    Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(context)

        .setContentTitle(onderwerp)
        .setContentText(name)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ninja)
        .setSound(soundUri)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ja, "Ja, ik heb ze ingenomen.", contentIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)

        .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager 
       = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotification.vibrate = new long[]{100, 200, 100, 500}; 
    mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;       

    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);

}
```

**Solution:**
In test activity OnCreate added this:

```
   NotificationManager notificationManager 
       = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.cancel(0);
```

Comment: did you try .setAutoCancel(true) before you build?maybe

Comment: Where are you canceling the notification from?

Comment: Edited the opening post. It should auto-cancel right? So I dont have to call anything.

Comment: You have to cancel it manually as soon as you receive your addAction intent in Test activity.

Comment: @kiruwka Can you put the code for that in an Answer?

Comment: Never mind its working now, I'll edit the OP. Edit- Lol, just saw your answer. Still flag it as the right answer. ;)

Comment: @user2883477 Ok great. Did you actually try what I suggested ?

Comment: @kiruwka Similar solution, only less complicated, see opening post.

Comment: @user2883477 well, I warn you about doing it in onCreate. I don't believe your activity will be always restarted (i.e. try clicking action button when Test activity already on screen - and let me know if still works). I think it is safer to do it the way I recommended.

Comment: @kiruwka Test activity will be finished in OnCreate too. It's there to send some stuff around. Otherwise I would use your suggestion ofcourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decided to use `Test` activity to receive the intent of your `addAction` call, then you must cancel notification when you receive the intent in the activity.

I also recommend that you add `requestCode` for the intent.

Here is the code :

to set the `requestCode` modify this :

```
static final int REQ_CODE = 101; // some number
// Notificatie trigger
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQ_CODE,
    new Intent(context, Test.class), 0);
```

to Handle intent in activity and dismiss the notification, in Test activity class :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
        // dismiss notification
        notificationManager.cancel(0);

        // handle your action
        // ...
    }
}
```

Hope that helps